# Index error returned while applying kernel to spectrogram

Tags: python, detection

I found this code online and feed it a text file with names of wavs but can't get it to work. It is a whale detector and applies a kernel to a spectrogram. I remember trying it before and having no issue with it but now I just can't get it to work. I've checked that my spectrograms were correctly calculated so I guess the error is not linked to my data but to the code itself.

```
files = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()

sig_ref, samp_ref = sf.read(files[0][:-1])
f_ref, t_ref = sg.spectrogram(sig_ref, samp_ref, 'hann', 16384, 10000)[:2]
f0_p = 10000 #average start frequency
f1_p = 30000 #average end frequency
bdwdth_p = 11.3 # average bandwidth
dur_p = 0.5 #average duration
[tvec_p, fvec_p, BlueKernel_p] = buildkernel(f0_p, f1_p, bdwdth_p, dur_p, f_ref, t_ref, samp_ref) #build kernel from input parameters
f0_m = 250 #average start frequency
f1_m = 900 #average end frequency
bdwdth_m = 400 # average bandwidth
dur_m = 1 #average duration
[tvec_m, fvec_m, BlueKernel_m] = buildkernel(f0_m, f1_m, bdwdth_m, dur_m, f_ref, t_ref, samp_ref) #build kernel from input parameters

time = []
conf = []
species = []

for file in files:
        sig, samp = sf.read(file[:-1])
        f, t, Sxx = sg.spectrogram(sig, samp, 'hann', 16384, 10000)
        CorrValP = cc(f, t, Sxx, tvec_p, fvec_p, BlueKernel_p)
        CorrValM = cc(f, t, Sxx, tvec_m, fvec_m, BlueKernel_m)
        np.save('test_dolphin', CorrValP)
        detectP = sg.find_peaks(CorrValP/max(CorrValP), height = 0.5)
        detectM = sg.find_peaks(CorrValM/max(CorrValM), height = 0.5)
        species.extend(['dolphin' for i in range(len(detectP))])
        time.extend(t[detectP])
        conf.extend(CorrValP[detectP]/np.amax(CorrValP))
        species.extend(['whale' for i in range(len(detectM))])
        time.extend(t[detectM])
        conf.extend(CorrValM[detectM]/np.amax(CorrValM))
        dic = {'file': np.tile(file, len(time)), 'species' : species, 'T' : time, 'confidence' : conf}
```

I get the following error :

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from scipy's find peaks.
It does not only returns the peaks but other information as well. Replace those lines:

```
detectP = sg.find_peaks(CorrValP/max(CorrValP), height = 0.5)[0]
detectM = sg.find_peaks(CorrValM/max(CorrValM), height = 0.5)[0]
```